# Authorization for subscriptions Graphql (Absinthe) with token

Tags: graphql, phoenix-framework, elixir, absinthe

I'm trying to add authentication to this *subscription test*, since I keep getting `Not Authorized` when I run `mix test`.
 I've seen that you need to add a login mutation to the `push_doc` function but I was wondering. Is there any way to use only the token to authenticate, just like regular mutations that use :

```
conn =
      build_conn()
      |> put_req_header("authorization", @token)
      |> get("/api", query: @query)

    assert json_response(conn, 200) == %{
       "data" => %{
          "authors" => [%{"name" => "Jennifer"}]
       }
    }
```

This is my current subscription test:

```
test "1. Subscribe to createAuthor", %{socket: socket} do

    # setup a subscription
    ref = push_doc(socket, @subscription)
    assert_reply(ref, :ok, %{subscriptionId: subscription_id})

    # run a mutation to trigger the subscription
    ref = push_doc(socket, @mutation)
    assert_reply(ref, :ok, reply)

    assert %{
         data: %{
           "createAuthor" => %{
             "name" => "Jennifer"
           }
         }
       } = reply

    # check to see if we got subscription data
    expected = %{
      result: %{
        data: %{
          "createAuthor" => %{
            "name" => "Jennifer"
          }
        }
      },
      subscriptionId: subscription_id
    }

    assert_push("subscription:data", push)
    assert expected == push
end
```

My general question is. Can I only pass the `token` (which I have hardcoded) into a function to authenticate for subscriptions?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do the test as follows, making the mutation using `put_req_header()`

```
test "1. Subscribe to createAuthor", %{socket: socket} do
    # setup a subscription
    ref = push_doc(socket, @subscription)
    assert_reply(ref, :ok, %{subscriptionId: subscription_id})

    # run a mutation to trigger the subscription
    conn =
      post(
        build_conn()
        |> put_req_header("authorization", @token),
        "/api",
        query: @mutation
      )

    assert json_response(conn, 200) == %{
             "data" => %{
               "createAuthor" => %{
                 "name" => "Jennifer"
               }
             }
           }

    # check to see if we got subscription data
    expected = %{
      result: %{
        data: %{
          "createAuthor" => %{
            "name" => "Jennifer"
          }
        }
      },
      subscriptionId: subscription_id
    }

    assert_push("subscription:data", push)
    assert expected == push
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a token with an expiry in like 100 years, signed with your key.  Hardcode that and it's good forever as long as you use the same SK.

Are you adding "Bearer" in front of your token?